# svnserve and apache serving the same SVN repository?

Tags: svn, apache, svnserve

Can one *safely* have the same SVN repository served by **both** svnserve and httpd ?

I have performance issues with **remote users** using httpd.

I wonder if this is feasible, recommended... ?

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. svnserve and web_dav can both serve from the same directory.

Our current setup is doing exactly this.

Comment: We did the install but faced a problem in SVN's internal folder rights (_Permission denied : Can't move db/txn-protorevs to 'db/revs_) because svnserve was launched with root privileges.

Comment: Make sure apache can access it. I tend to add apache to the group 'developers' and then group-own all the svn dirs to the developers group.

Comment: @KOGI - I need both the configuration svnserve and http support from browser. I have installed svn 1.9.2 custom install and running the svnserve as daemon in linux. i used apr, apr-util, serf but my http is not working. how to make http working in browser.

Comment: @arunp - sorry, I don't know. This answer is 4.5 years old at this point and I haven't used SVN in a very long time.